# How to pull a piece of data from a custom field in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I need to pull a piece of data from a custom field in the regarded account or case and pull it into a field in a phone call form. (its just to identify which account group the call took place from)

I am not sure of the javascript code to pull from the regarded account or case.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can achieve this using a workflow (but will not be realtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in javascript, you'll have to access the organization endpoint and retrieve the account/case record. The main form contains the regarding lookup field, which will have the GUID, display name, and entity name of the record. The CRM 2011 SDK has some sample code for retrieving records in Javascript, and they even have a library you could use that does all the hard work for you.